# using xlwt to filling in a cell with color and a cell without color python

Tags: python-3.x, loops, for-loop, iteration, xlwt

I have my list

```
mylist=[['w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w', '', '', '', '', ''],['', '', '', '', '', '', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'w', '', '', '', '', '']]
```

I want to just color the elem in the list that are 'w' I have a code but its coloring all of the columns instead of just the ones that are ''

```
import xlwt 
from xlwt import Workbook 

row = 1
for values in my_list:
    for col, data in enumerate(values):
        if values=='w':
            style=xlwt.easyxf('pattern: pattern solid, fore_colour blue;' 'font: colour black, bold True, name Calibri, height 180; align: vert centre, horiz centre;border: left thin,right thin,top thin,bottom thin') 
            sheet1.write(6+row, 1+col, data, style=style) 
        else:
            style=xlwt.easyxf('pattern: pattern solid, fore_colour white;' 'font: colour black, bold True, name Calibri, height 180; align: vert centre, horiz centre;border: left thin,right thin,top thin,bottom thin') 
            sheet1.write(6+row, 1+col, data, style=style) 

    row = row + 1 

wb.save('example.xls')
```

Not sure if I missed a iteration of the each element in values

Comment: I forgot part of the code # Workbook is created 
wb = Workbook() 

# add_sheet is used to create sheet. 
sheet1 = wb.add_sheet('Sheet 1')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `values` and should be using `data` to refer to a single element in your inner list, so instead of:

```
if values=='w':
```

you would have

```
if data=='w':
```